# DXGI_ERROR_DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR on DrawInstanced() method at feature level 9_3

Tags: directx, directx-11

I've got following problem with `DrawInstanced()` call in my DirectX 11 code. When I call DrawInstanced() using feature level 10_0 or higher, everything works as expected, but when I switch to feature level 9_3, I get following error in debug output:

```
D3D11: Removing Device.
D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11Device::RemoveDevice: Device removal has been triggered for the following reason (DXGI_ERROR_DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR: There is strong evidence that the driver has performed an undefined operation; but it may be because the application performed an illegal or undefined operation to begin with.). [ EXECUTION WARNING #379: DEVICE_REMOVAL_PROCESS_POSSIBLY_AT_FAULT]
```

According to [these msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876(v=vs.85).aspx), Instancing should be supported on Directx 9_3 feature level. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that while Instancing is supported on feature level 9_3, the only api that works is `DrawIndexedInstanced` as per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ID3D11DeviceContext_DrawIndexedInstanced), so I had to adapt my code to work with indexed instancing.